# Convert (log n)^n to the form n^x, for some x

Tags: logarithm

How do I convert (log n)^n to the form n^x, for some x? I'd like to compare the big-O runtime of (log n)^n to n^(log n) directly. Intuitively, I think that (log n)^n grows faster since the exponent grows faster but I'm not sure how to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: You might get better answers here http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure about where to put this question since this question also mentions big-O notation. Also, I've seen other logarithm questions on stack overflow.

Comment: It definitely fits here as well, *I* think you might get better answers there, but you might get some good answers here too.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most rigorous way to show something, but I guess this may help build intuition to what's happening, and hopefully flesh it out to a proof

You want to compare $\log(n)^n$ with $n^{\log(n)}$. Take the logarithm of both and then the square root. You then want to compare $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\log(\log(n)))}$ with $\log(n)$. Now any power of $n$ is going to be faster than $\log(n)$. Thus $\log(n)^n$ increases faster than $n^{\log(n)}$.

(How do I format this right?)